# Skip a setInterval every X loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, setinterval

I have a function that gets triggered every 10 seconds with a `setInterval();` loop, and I'd like it to skip a call every 60 seconds. So the function would be executed at 10s, 20s, 30s, 40s and 50s but wouldn't be called at 60s, then gets called at 70s and so on.

Is there any straightforward way to do this, or do I have to tinker with incrementing a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say the variable option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript run a function inside a loop every x iterations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198373/javascript-run-a-function-inside-a-loop-every-x-iterations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this, use the simple `modulo` math and a counter.

```
var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
      count += 1;
      if(count % 6 !== 0) {
          // your code
      } 
}, 10000);
```